# split Useragent preg_split

Tags: php, preg-split

im trying to split the User agent with preg_split.

```
My regex is:    [\/();,]
```

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0

what show me this result:

```
array (
  0 => 'Mozilla',
  1 => '5.0 ',
  2 => 'Windows NT 6.1',
  3 => ' WOW64',
  4 => ' rv:45.0',
  5 => ' Gecko',
  6 => '20100101 Firefox',
  7 => '45.0',
)
```

its splitting me not like im want. is there a way to split the Useragent like this

```
array (
  0 => 'Mozilla',
  1 => '5.0 ',
  2 => 'Windows NT 6.1',
  3 => ' WOW64',
  4 => ' rv:45.0',
  5 => ' Gecko',
  6 => '20100101
  7 => Firefox',
  8 => '45.0',
)
```

with space but inside the (...) only with [;]

Comment: Would this work for you? `Array
(
    [0] => Mozilla
    [1] => 5.0
    [2] => Windows
    [3] => NT
    [4] => 6.1
    [5] => WOW64
    [6] => rv:45.0
    [7] => Gecko
    [8] => 20100101
    [9] => Firefox
    [10] => 45.0
)`

Comment: when im adding a [/s] then it will show me like this.. but im want inside the ( ) only with [;]

Comment: I don't thinks that's possible to reliably split the user agent as you want.